# Read a text file and save value as variable in python

Tags: python

I am new to Python and please excuse if my question sounds dumb. I have a function which reads a text file and records the first line and passes the same to another function. But I am not able to figure out a way to store the value to a global variable which can be reused again.

Sample of text file. Holds only one line:
1234567

Script to read file:

```
def main():
    input = file(infile, 'r')
    lines = input.readlines()
    input.close()
    i = 0
    for line in lines:
        i += 1
        id = int(line)
        WorkOnIDThread(id)
main()
```

So basically I want help with storing the id as a global variable which I could reuse through out the script.

Any help on this would be really helpful.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with passing the variable around to your functions. Global variables can be a bad idea.

Comment: Agree with @Falmarri avoid using globals. It's bad practice.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to share with other function, use global

```
id = 0
def main():
    global id
    ...
```

Answer (score -1):

```
id = 0 # declare it in the global scope

def main():
    # using the global keyword will let you access it in the function scope
    global id 
    input = file(infile, 'r')
    lines = input.readlines()
    input.close()
    i = 0
    for line in lines:
        i += 1
        id = int(line)
        WorkOnIDThread(id)
main()
print id
```

Comment: Thank you very much.. That exactly what i did just now to fix the issue and by the time I figured it out to wanted to come back and say all is well I saw the response. Thank again for the help!!!

Comment: Except that using the variable name of `id` is particularly bad, considering it overwrites the built-in `id()` function.

Comment: Agree.. ID was just used for representation. Used a different naming convention.. Thanks!